# Inline MudDialog always visible when used inside another MudDialog

Tags: c#, .net-core, dialog, blazor, mudblazor

When I use an inline MudDialog inside a MudDialog (which is opened with DialogService), the inline dialog is always visible. Also the it is not shown as a dialog, but directly inside the page.

This works on normal components, but not nested in MudDialogs open with DialogService.

```
<MudDialog IsVisible="false" Options="dialogOptions">
            <DialogContent>
                <MudGrid>
                    @DialogContent
                </MudGrid>
            </DialogContent>
</MudDialog>
```

Is there anything I can do to use inline dialogs inside another dialog?

Comment: Why can't you put the MudDialog outside of the other MudDialog?

Comment: Because the first MudDialog opens a component which contains a MudTable. In the MudTable Headers there is an inline MudDialog to apply filters for the columns. I don't see any comfortable way of doing this outside the first dialog, since this table should be reusable wether in a dialog or not.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot define properties storing this filter values outside the scope of the first MudDialog?

Comment: Yes the table is in its own component and should contain all the defintions for the headers inside it. I cannot define this outside of the popup since this makes it non reusable.

Comment: I do not think you will be able to inline the inner MudDialog. You could pull the inner dialog out of the MudTable into its own file and call it with DialogService.  You can still keep the header information in the table and pass it to the dialog via parameters.  The filters can be applied to the table through the dialog.Result.